# PHP: Trouble With Allowed Memory Size

Tags: php, apache-flex, memory, mysqli

I'm using a Flex application to make two calls to my database via PHP. On my second call I'm getting an error which shows in my proxy debugger as `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes)` which is very confusing to me because the first search must have taken a LOT of memory.
Just before I show code i'll say that I have a `users` table containing only 15 rows, with only 10 small columns and I have a `businesses` table which contains 19 rows with 19 columns. so basically I don't have a lot of data in the first place.

My first has the following Flex code within a function:

> user=new User();
>     user.facebookid = facebookidLbl.text;
>   getUserIDResult.token = userService.getUserByID(user);

Which calls the following function in PHP:

> public function getUserByID ($item)

```
{
    $getfbid = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $item->facebookid);

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,

    "SELECT

          users.facebookid,

          users.dob,

          users.latitude,

          users.longitude

       FROM users where users.facebookid='{$getfbid}'");

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    $row = new User();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $row->facebookid, $row->dob, $row->latitude, $row->longitude);

    if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {

        return $row;

    } else {

        return null;

    }

    mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);

    mysqli_close($this->connection);

}
```

Then the second function is has only the following line in flex: `getBusinessResult.token = businessService.getBusiness(business);`

Which calls the following PHP:

> public function getBusiness ($item)

```
{
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, "SELECT * FROM businesses");


while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) !== false) 
{
$data[] = $row;
}
```

The second function takes at least a minute to complete, then I get the error mentioned above, whereas the first function happens almost instantly. I would assume it's the second function, but the error also states that it's trying to allocate 40961 bytes, which is a lot smaller than the quota, so it must be the first search that's doing this.
I'm really stuck, so any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 40961 bytes)
```

This error does'nt mean that it failed to allocate `40961` bytes but it means that the quota was exceeded when an additional 40961 bytes was tried to be alloted. Looking at your code:

```
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) !== false) 
{
$data[] = $row;
}
```

You are saving each row in an array. Assuming, you have a very large table, the allocation fails to save such a large array.

Comment: So what do you recommend I do?

Comment: @user1077544: That depends on why you want to store it?

Comment: I need to display the data in Google Maps within my Flex app, so I need a for loop in Flex that will allow me to create markers from the returned data. I had planned to do this by storing the data as an Array, so I created an array on the PHP side of things.

Here is what my Flex code looks like with the results:
`var businesslist:ArrayCollection = event.result as ArrayCollection;  
    for(var i:int=0; i<businesslist.length; i++)  
    {
     var businessMarker:Marker = new Marker(new LatLng(businesslist[i].latitude, businesslist[i].longitude));  
     Map.addOverlay(businessMarker);
    }`

Comment: @user1077544: If using the whole array at a time is only solution then you can store the array in a file using `FILE_APPEND` keyword. I don't know about flex but there must be methods to retrieve that file and decode it (hope so).

Comment: Apparently using the AMFPHP decodes it automatically, but for a failsafe method I could always get the PHP to turn the results into XML, then process the XML onto the map in Flex.

Comment: @user1077544: SO whats the problem?

Comment: Well the problem is still why I can't do an array without it taking up a ridiculous amount of memory; I mean I have such a small database.